# How can you get setState.of(context) in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an app with a ModalProgresHUD on most pages.  Usually I can pass a fucntion to, for example, onTap, to any widget in this tree, to turn this spinner on/off.

But sometimes this seems difficult and I'd like to access the fields and/or setState on a State somewhere else, up the WidgetTree.

One option seems to be to move all the logic into the top Widget, and pass handlers down to access these methods, but that feels cludgy.

```dart
    class StatefullPage ..... {
       String _someImportantField;
       set someImportantField(String newValue) {
          _someImportantField = newValue;
          if(mounted) setState((){});
       }

       ...
    }

    class StateOfSomethingElse ... {
       Future doSomeWorkThatAffectsTheParent() async {
          await something.then((String newResult) {
          State.of(context).someImportantField = newResult;// HOW TO DO THIS
       }
       ...
    }
```

Comment: You may want to look into provider/Inheritedwidget

Comment: I've been meaning to.  Now I have a reason.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of state management do you use? It looks that you are simply using setState and there's no problem with that. But to do the sort of think you want i think it's better to use something like provider or redux to handle the state of your app.

Using Provider for example, you can provide a value on the top of your tree and can get this value anywhere on your widget tree to do your logic.

Comment: I'm very much shying away from StateManagement Plugins.  Maybe I should not.

For now "state" that affects what is visible on the current "page" is kept in fields of the State.  Data that is shared between Widgets are kept in either Singleton widgets, or in Globally instantiated objects.

Comment: I totally got your desire to avoid state management possibilities. But when you got your app in a state that you have to share state beetween multiples widgets i guess is better to hold on with a state management more robust to say.